# MySQL sort by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table.

```
id    name     data
1     DAN      xxxxxxxxx
2     ANTONY   xxxxxxxxx
3     DAN      xxxxxxxxx
4     DAN      xxxxxxxxx
5     JOSEPH   xxxxxxxxx
6     ANTONY   xxxxxxxxx
7     JOSEPH   xxxxxxxxx
```

I want to first sort the table using ID and then group by name.
eg.

```
7    JOSEPH  xxxxxxxxx
5    JOSEPH  xxxxxxxxx
6    ANTONY  xxxxxxxxx
2    ANTONY  xxxxxxxxx
4    DAN     xxxxxxxxx
3    DAN     xxxxxxxxx
1    DAN     xxxxxxxxx
```

I tried various combinations of ORDER BY and also tried ORDER BY FIELD but unable to get the desired result

Comment: have you tried `select * from table order by id,name` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but didn't get the expected results

Comment: ORDER BY correlated subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
select *, (select max(id) from tab t2 where t2.name = t1.name) m
from tab t1
order by m desc, id desc;
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6185bb9d2fbd11bcee3ad29c6271c437)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *window function* to get the maximum id for each name and use them for ordering purpose.

```
SELECT *,
        MAX(id) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id DESC) Ord
FROM table t
ORDER BY Ord DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in the `order by`, so you can express this as:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name) desc, id desc;
```